# Remove specific duplicates (all but latest)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When removing duplicate rows, using the below query from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157977/Remove-Duplicate-Rows-from-a-Table-in-SQL-Server) tutorial, how would I go about forcing which of the found duplicates to remove?

```
DELETE FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE 
    WHERE AUTOID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(AUTOID) _
FROM dbo.ATTENDANCE 
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID,ATTENDANCE_DATE)
```

And this works great. The reason why I am using this one is because the only unique id available is one in the `IDENTITY` column. And to determine if there are duplicate rows I have to look at a combination of multiple columns.

But if I have a set of duplicate rows how do I / how does SQL Server decide which to remove? And how would I force it to remove all but the one with the highest `IDENTITY` value?

```
EMPLOYEE_ID     ATTENDANCE_DATE     AUTOID
A001            2011-01-01          1
A001            2011-01-01          2
```

If I would run the query now it happens to remove the second one, with `AUTOID` 2. But I am trying to remove all but this one (because this is the one latest added).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement a query using `row_number()` to delete everything but the most recent row. This partitions the data by the `employee_id` and orders it by the `autoId` column, then you delete everything that is greater than the first row number:

```
;with cte as
(
  select [EMPLOYEE_ID], [ATTENDANCE_DATE], [AUTOID],
    row_number() over(partition by [EMPLOYEE_ID], [ATTENDANCE_DATE] 
                      order by  [AUTOID] desc) rn
  from dbo.ATTENDANCE
)
delete 
from cte 
where rn > 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06399/10)